# Can't edit .profile from recovery

Tags: recovery-mode

I'm trying to use cat from recovery menu. What happens it will open, but it stays in the terminal prompt. It will load the file, but I can't edit it. How can I get it to be editable? I need to remove one thing in it.

Comment: If you're in recovery mode you need to make sure that you remount the drive as read / write or you won't be able to modify any files since it boots to read only mode.  `sudo mount -o remount,rw /`

Answer (score 7):

Editing a file involves using an editor, not `cat`, which just prints the content. In Ubuntu, the standard editor for the terminal is `nano`. In the recovery prompt, first `cd` to the directory where the file resides that you want to change. Then open the file for editing with the command `nano name_of_your_file`. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to save, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit the editor.